# C# + DirectShow.NET = Simple WebCam access?

Tags: c#, directshow, webcam, directshow.net

I have found an [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/markhsch/archive/2007/11/19/c-webcam-user-control-source.aspx) for accessing a webcam in C#. The example uses the [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library. I have tried to understand the code, but so far the only thing I could figure out is that somehow the usercontrol calls directshow to draw directly to the surface of the user control.

I want to access each frame and put it into a Bitmap object. How can I tell when a new frame arrived? How can I capture this new frame into a Bitmap Object?

This might be simple to answer if you know your way around DirectShow.NET.

Comment: Now days DirectShow.NET is a dead project. Sorry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use the [ISampleGrabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376984(VS.85).aspx) interface there are many c++ examples on the net on how to use it, it will give you data the in RGB raw format which you can feed into the Bitmap class.

There is also an open source library called [Touchless](http://www.codeplex.com/touchless) it has a project in code which takes a web cam and give you a callback every time a new frame arrived.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I get the qedit.h needed for compiling touchless' WebCamLib? I have downloaded both the windows sdk and the directx sdk, but could not find it anywhere.

Comment: know issue, you need the an old August 2007 DirectX SDK. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=529F03BE-1339-48C4-BD5A-8506E5ACF571&displaylang=en

Comment: I have installed the August 2007 SDK, but havn't found the qedit.h in the include dir or anywere else.

Comment: My experience on compiling the WebCamLib: you need to download a ~222M file "dx9sdk.exe", its a very old directx 9 sdk (2002), a google search for the filename will help you. After the install in the include dir, you will find the qedit.h. You have to specify this directory in the project properties of WebCamLib. Make sure to compile it in Release, or Vista will cry. Also you might get and error and have to change a POINTER_64 constant to __ptr64.

Comment: Success! Thanks, Touchless was great help :)

Comment: @Shay Erlichmen: the _ISampleGrabber_ API "may be removed from future releases of Windows". see on the link you have provided...

Comment: @itsho well on metro apps it is no longer supported

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to take a look at this article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library ; it is based on Touchless WebCam capturing component (but without other parts from Touchless SDK).

Comment: @fretje tnx for notice, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

If you found Touchless useful, but would like to use the latest DirectX SDK, try getting the latest source after change 31008 at http://touchless.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx

Comment: codeplex has shutdown, any alternate way to access touchless?