# C# video input routines

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming

Can someone point me towards a good article or tutorial on how to access TV tuner and/or web cams from C#? I looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [this question about web cams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833724/c-directshow-net-simple-webcam-access) and [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), which is a managed wrapper for the DirectShow component in DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally something that the manufacturer of your video hardware would provide, usually in the form of an SDK.

Depending on what you want to do, this might help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx