# camera application in windows form

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-c++, camera, camera-calibration

Basically, i want to write a windows form program like any other webcam's control program in c++ for a custom camera. this camera has some API like grab pictures and etc.
  i have never done a camera application before, so i am a bit confused. 
  for the "preview" function like other webcam softwares, is it like just polling the .JPEG pictures from the camera and display it on the windows form screen in every .1 second? is it like that simple?
  does anyone knows what the basically idea for writing a webcam software?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait - Windows Forms is a .NET technology. Do you want to use Windows Forms (e.g. in C#)? Or do you want to use native code C++?

For C#, look at [DirectShow.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833724/c-directshow-net-simple-webcam-access) for simple webcam access.

For C++, use DirectShow.

Comment: actually, it is not a webcam. it is a surveillance cam with a frame grabber.