# How to access webcam using C#?

Tags: c#, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# + DirectShow.NET = Simple WebCam access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833724/c-sharp-directshow-net-simple-webcam-access)

How do you switch on/off the webcam using C#? I want to create a program with a start/end button that would access the laptop webcam.

Comment: May be this link should help you http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15208/create-a-switch-that-turns-onoff-video-streams-in.html

Answer (score 5):

AForge gives a nice solution:
http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Expression Encoder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4